# startImageStream in flutter returns imageFromStream where imageFromStream.planes[0].height is null

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, tflite

I'm creating a flutter project for which live camera stream is required, for which we are using camera,
problem here is i'm unable to figure out how should I call startImageStream method so that it always return a object without null values.
we need to convert CameraImage to Uint8List => for which we need different planes.height but because they are null i'm stuck.

calling preprocessImage is of no use since imageFromStream.planes[0].height is null.
any help.
[the values of the object imageFromStream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Gfg.png)

pubspec.yaml dependencies

```
camera: ^0.10.0
tflite_flutter: ^0.10.0
```

initState and dispose =>

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initCamera();
    loadModel();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    interpreter.close();
    cameraController.stopImageStream();
    cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Implementation

```
initCamera() {
    try{
    cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    cameraController.initialize().then((value) async{
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        cameraController.startImageStream((imageFromStream) async{
          if (!isWorking){
            isWorking = true;
            print(imageFromStream);
            print(imageFromStream.planes[0].height);
            preprocessImage(imageFromStream);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    }
    catch(e){print(e);}
  }
```

we need to convert CameraImage to Uint8List =>

```
preprocessImage(CameraImage cameraImage) async {

    final planes = cameraImage.planes;

    final yPlane = planes[0];
    final uvPlane = planes[1];

    final ySize = yPlane.bytesPerRow * yPlane.height!;
    final uvSize = uvPlane.bytesPerRow * uvPlane.height! ~/ 2;

    // Create a new Uint8List with the combined size of Y and UV planes
    final bytes = Uint8List(ySize + uvSize);

    // Fill the Y plane
    bytes.setRange(0, ySize, yPlane.bytes);

    // Fill the UV plane
    final uvOffset = ySize;
    for (var i = 0; i < uvPlane.height!; i++) {
      final srcOffset = i * uvPlane.bytesPerRow;
      final destOffset = uvOffset + i * uvPlane.width! * 2;
      bytes.setRange(destOffset, destOffset + uvPlane.bytesPerRow, uvPlane.bytes, srcOffset);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```dart
imageFromStream.planes[0].height
```

It should be:

```dart
imageFromStream.height
```